# Request validation failed for action "Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Validate\Interceptor" [] []

Tags: magento2, product

Can someone guide me on where I can find the issue the validator is concerned over?  This is Magento 2.3.4, and the database has gone through data migration.  There are several products that when I display them and then try to save I get an error, the message in the log is what appears in the title of this post.

> [2020-03-01 17:36:03] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action
>   "Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Validate\Interceptor" []
>   []

I have been unsuccessful in finding a place in the code but have determined a breaking point by trial and error. I created a new product and gave each a drop down with 5 values.  The system will allow 9 of these options with 5 values each for the drop down.  Anymore than that, another option or another drop down value will give me the error.

So it seems to either be a Magento 2 issue or an interface issue into the database?
All I get on the backend is that I received a technical issue and try again later and the debug file points to an interceptor.  I am getting hits on it within the request and response functions but never have I been able to print large amounts of data like an object from Magento2  without crashing the system.  Any hints here would be greatly appreciated.

These products are currently in Magento 1 with up to 8 options and various drop downs, radio buttons and text fields associated with each option.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2):

GOOD GRIEF .... max_input_vars

I came across this years ago in Magento1 .... didn't even cross my mind for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with these below values in your php.ini file. Try updating to what i shared below.

```
php_value post_max_size 52428800 # 50MB
php_value upload_max_filesize 52428800 # 50MB
php_value max_execution_time 300 # 5 minutes
```

reference link : [ini_set() and post_max_size](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/ini-set-and-post-max-size/7414/4)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Increase `max_input_vars` in `php.ini`

> max_input_vars = 2000 ; put your value here

**Explain:**

When you save product in admin, Magento call controller

> /catalog/product/validate/id/{product_id}

And you can get the following response

[image]

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}
```

This happens when the number of input variables in the request body exceeds the configuration.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars